# Embedding Gist link in blogger.com

Tags: git, blogger, gist

I want to embed gist links into my free blogger web blog. In Wordpress I just have to copy page the gist link and everything is handled by the Wordpress but this is not working in Blogger.

Can anyone tell me the correct way to embed a gist link in blogger.com.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to follow [Moski](https://github.com/moski)'s project [gist-Blogger](https://github.com/moski/gist-Blogger), detailed in his [blog post](http://blog.moski.me/2012/01/gist-with-bloggers-dynamic-views.html).

> At the end of each of your blog posts, include the following code using the HTML editor:

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/moski/gist-Blogger/master/public/gistLoader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> Now to include any gist template just add the following anywhere in your blog post.

```
<div class="gistLoad" data-id="GistID" id="gist-GistID">Loading ....</div>
```

It is illustrated in this blog post "[How to Embed gist code samples in Blogger](http://excelramblings.blogspot.fr/2012/08/how-to-embed-gist-code-samples-in.html)"

Comment: I tried above method. Replaced the GistID with my gist id and it did not work. Is there any other change required.